# Using externally cloned Git repository in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

At the moment I'm using TFS with Git as version control system. Sometimes I clone repositories with other tools than the default Visual Studio tooling, but (obviously) Visual Studio doesn't recognize or even know about these repositories. I'm currently facing the following screen:

[image: Visual Studio - Team Explorer - Home]

Is there any way I can link or map the existing repositories to Visual Studio? Note that the repositories already contains the correct remote URL and the local repository is fully in sync with the remote repository. In fact, it was cloned from this remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Team Explorer connect page:  in the local repositories section, click add to add the existing repository that you cloned.

Team Explorer will notice that you have cloned this from TFS and the extended functionality will be available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That adds them to the 'Local Git Repository' section, but doesn't show options related to pull requests and builds. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Caramiriel No, it should.  Is the URL specified the same in your git remote as when you connect to TFS?  If you exit VS and restart, does the behavior change?

Comment: Ah I see. The remote origin url doesn't contain the fully qualified name in TFS, but it does in the external tooling. Changing the url makes TFS instantly recognize the repository. I think I'll have to match these up in order to generate the same url's on both ends and then it'll work. Thanks!